# Компиляция программы C++ \ Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi

Если скомпилировать программу в Windows 7 x86
и запустить её в Windows x64 запуститься, будет ли работать.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Если не забудете вместе с программой положить необходимые ей библиотеки (DLL) компилятора *C++* или *Delphi*, то запустится и будет работать.

64-битные ОС семейства *Windows* содержат в себе слой совместимости с 32-битными программами. Этот слой состоит из специальной подсистемы *WOW64*. *WOW64* - это почти полный набор системных библиотек 32-битной версии, которые расположены в каталоге `%SYSTEM_ROOT%\SysWOW64`. При запуске 32-битного приложения операционная система подменяет для программы каталог `%SYSTEM_ROOT%\System32` на `%SYSTEM_ROOT%\SysWOW64`. Также подменяются некоторые ветки реестра.

Фактически можно считать, что для запуска 32-битного приложения 64-битная ОС производит некий аналог виртуализации.

Answer (score 5):

Да, 32-разрядные программы работают в 64-разрядной Windows.

Comment: Я бы еще добавил... при условии, что программу скомпилированную на Windows 7 x86 человек не будет пытаться запускать на предыдущих версиях Windows (пусть и 64-х битных).

Comment: Да. Будет работать, если не использовать WinAPI, которые есть в семерке и нет в предыдущих версиях. В противном случае - нет.

Comment: И не все 32-х битные программы в принципе запустятся на 64-х битной семерке. Для таких случаев есть XP Mode. Хотя сама MIcrosoft утверждает, что это разработка для обеспечения безопасности запуска старых программ. Но при этом пишется "Большинство программ, совместимых с Windows Vista и Windows XP, хорошо работают в Windows 7." Заметьте - не все. В особенности это касается драйверов :) А что компилирует автор вопроса, какие WinApi функции использует и что у него в настройках компилятора выставлено - сие есть тайна покрытая мраком.

Comment: @MaxZS XP Mode, по большому счету - запуск приложения от имени админа, поскольку подавляющее большинство проблем приложений, написанных во времена WinXP связано с попытками открыть HKLM на чтение+запись, или запись файлов в Program Files/Windows и другие действия, запрещенные политикой безопасности. Драйвера на Delphi не пишут со времен D3, а поскольку автор задался таким вопросом, не думаю, что он вообще самостоятельно использует WinAPI. А все что зашито внутри Delphi - совместимо.

Comment: @kami XP Mode совсем не похоже на запуск приложения от имени админа. Это скорее похоже на виртуальную машину c Win XP. Попробуйте - узнаете. И посмотрите где образ и сколько места занимает :) . И если бы было так (запуск от админа), то не надо было бы изобретать XP Mode. Возможно, Вы путаете запуск в режиме совместимости с XP с запуском XP Mode?

Comment: @MaxZS, все правильно, путаю. Если честно - только после Вашего комментария узнал про "настоящий" XP Mode. :) Свой коммент не удаляю, поскольку описанные в нем проблемы действительно являются "подавляющим большинством".